# Calculations for the drop of energy in a RLC circuit

Tags: power, oscillator, frequency, passive-networks

Suppose we have this RLC circuit and every component is perfect ( resistors have 0 impedance and inductors and capacitors have 0 resistance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJSdG3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assume the capacitor is precharged and 'holds' 1J of energy.Also the inductor has a value such as the strength of the magnetic around the inductor has maximum possible strength and the induced voltage(EMF)is  below the diodes reverse breakdown voltage.

The reverse current of a diode is typically around 10nA(?) . The ohmic resistance of the circuit is 10mΩ.

So the total power dissipated on the resistor every second is 2x10x10x10^3x10^6 = 200x10^9 = 2x10^8W.

So for the circuit to become discharged it must oscillate 5x10^4 times = 50000 times.Since the frequency of the oscillation will be very small this can be running for years without refresh.

Is that correct?

Comment: No . your model is incorrect. The series C will be the reverse Voltage diode variable capacitance and much lower leakage current.  W is power not energy

Comment: The diodes pass virtually no current, maybe 10nA. 1W is a measure of power, not energy.

Comment: Oups sorry. I will correct that.

Comment: It is not that easy to calculate, because to analyze this circuit, a more complete model of diodes have to be used, which also includes the junction capacitance, etc. so your best chances to study this circuit is to either study about a non-linear model of diodes (both for forward bias and reverse bias) and write equations and solved them or simulate the above in any circuit simulation software.

Comment: Why is the "ohmic resistance of the circuit" different from the value of R1? What assumptions are you making about the damping of the circuit? How do you assume that the amount of energy lost in each cycle is constant such that all of the energy will be lost in some fixed number of cycles?

Comment: The realistic model for this high impedance loop is quite different than what you assume for cap RC=T leakage and diode dV/dt = I/C leakage current and reverse capacitance. So learn more about component characteristics before attempting this. But in theory high Q reactive oscillation but short time constant in the cap.

Comment: Just it was an attempt to make an RLC circuit which could practically last forever but now I realize since the frequency is very big a considerable amount of energy will be lost every oscillation despite small currents running through the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simulation that I just quickly did

[image]

and here are the results:

[image]

from the simulation, it can be seen that it took ~670,000 seconds (=7.75462963 days) to discharge the capacitor. I have chosen capacitor value to be 2 micro farads and initial voltage of 1000 volts, which means it will store the energy of `0.5 * 2 * (10^-6) * (1000) * (1000) = 1 J`

I have chosen the value of Inductor at random.

Thankyou.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot.So it will need recharging from an external source every 7.5 days.That's not bad except it is a bit unrealistic (1000V)?

Comment: Where can I download your program?

Comment: What happens if you put the capacitor at 20mF and the voltage at 10V?

Comment: @HelenaWells yes it is unrealistic and moreover I am 100% sure that in practice, this is not what you get because i have used ideal model of capacitor and inductor. And yes 1000V is not practical ! And https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBuaqeLPzB7IgXhNsML8S2gqbxurnTXg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I assume that the total resistance of the capacitor inductor is 10mΩ.(and anyway every element of the circuit)

Comment: You need to run the simulation longer. The current is not settled, and the energy in the inductor will (partially) transfer back into the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

From personal research I have found that the ohmic resistance of a diode is approximately 25Ohms.

The total resistance will bw 2x25 = 50Ohms.

The initial energy stored in the capacitor is 1J.The power dissipated on the resistor is 10^5x50= 5x10^4=10^3/2 W.

L = 1H.

C = 20mF.

The frequency of the RLC oscillation is 1/sqrt(LC) = 1/sqrt(1x10^3x20) = 1/0.15 = 6.5s

In every oscillation the energy dissipated on the resistor will be 6.5/2x10^3=0.003J.

So the total time for the circuit to run out of time is: 33s(?).If we pick a typical 1mH inductor the total time will be 1000x33 = 33000s or 500 min or 8.2h which is very good.

Comment: `10^5x50= 5x10^4`. There may be a mistake in this calculation. `1/sqrt(LC) = 1/sqrt(1x10^3x20)`. In this one too.

Comment: Also The frequency of the RLC oscillation is 1/sqrt(LC) = 1/sqrt(1x10^3x20) = 1/0.15 = 6.5s is actually 6.5Hz  = 0.15 sec.